# LEFT JOIN Query with JPA not working (select new entity with users that have n documents)

Tags: join, left-join, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, aggregate-functions

may anybody help me with this task...

persistence provider is eclipselink 2.6.

i want to retrieve a list of users that may have 0 or n documents. because both tables have a few columns i want to use **SELECT NEW Entity (userId, amountDocuments)**, i only need the user-id and the amount of documents for this task.  if the user hasn't any documents yet, "0" should be shown, e.g.:

UserId:            1  2  3  4 
AmountDocs:   0  1  0  3

Mapping for **Documents** in Entity **User** is as follows:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "user", targetEntity = UserDocument.class)
@OrderBy("sortOrder ASC")
@JoinFetch(JoinFetchType.OUTER) 
protected List<UserDocument>documents;
```

Mapping for **User** in Entity **UserDocument** is as follows:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
protected User user;
```

and here is the jpa-query:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT 
NEW user.entity.User(u.id,count(doc.user)) FROM User u 
LEFT JOIN u.documents doc ON doc.user = u 
AND doc.active = 't' 
GROUP BY u.id
```

Problem is, that i **only retrieve those two users who have documents that match doc.active='t'**.

I also tried it with SIZE(u.documents) which also just returns two users and additionally wrong document-count values.

What is wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are you counting users?  count(doc.user) forces an inner join between doc and user, when all you really want is the doc count itself.  Count either on doc or doc.id

Comment: For issues with size, you will need to turn SQL logging on and show the statement that gets generated.  I suspect you are trying to filter documents from the count that aren't active ='t' which can't be factored into size, and that you might have added an inner join somewhere else by mistake

Comment: yes, your're right. i saw the problem with counting users instead of documents. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

finally after spending hours with that simple stuff, the right solution came with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   NEW user.entity.User(u.id,count(doc)) FROM User u 
    LEFT JOIN u.documents doc ON doc.user = u AND doc.active = 't' 
       GROUP BY u.id
```

i have to count the left joined documents itself not the users.